# Error while adding a button in a view OpenERP 7

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo

I've added a button in the view that i've created but i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'student_student' object has no attribute 'set_age'
```

here's the student_info.py file:

```
from osv import osv, fields


class student_student(osv.osv):
    _name = 'student.student'
    _inherit = 'student.student' #in another question on stackoverflow they said that writing this solved the same error, but it hasn't worked for me
    _columns = {
            'name' : fields.char('Student Name', size = 16, required = True, translate = True),
            'age' : fields.integer('Age'),
            'percentage' : fields.float('Percentage', help = 'This field will add average marks of the students out of 100'),
            'gender' : fields.selection([('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female')], 'Gender'),
            'active' : fields.boolean('Active'),
            'notes' : fields.text('Details'),
            }
    _defaults = {
            'name' : 'Atul',
            'active' : True,
            'age' : 13,
            }
    def set_age(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        for prod in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            my_age = 33 
        self.write(cr, uid, prod.id, {'age': my_age })

student_student()
```

and here's the student_info_view.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>


<!--Student search view-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_search" >
    <field name="name">student.search</field>
    <field name="model">student.student</field>
    <field name="type">search</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string = "student information search">
     <field name="name" string = "Student Name" />
         <field name="gender" string = "Gender" />  
         <field name="age" string = "Age" />
    </search>
    </field>
</record>


<!--Student tree View-->
<record id="student_student_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">student.result.tree</field>
   <field name="model">student.student</field>
   <field name="type">tree</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
     <tree string="Student_result">  
       <field name="name" />  
       <field name="age" />
       <field name="percentage"/> 
       <field name="gender"/>  
       <field name="active"/>
       </tree>
   </field>
 </record>


<!--Student Form View-->
<record id="student_student_form" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">student.result.form</field>
<field name="model">student.student</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
     <form string="Student_result">  
       <field name="name" />  
       <field name="age" />
       <field name="percentage"/> 
       <field name="gender"/>  
       <field name="active"/>
       <field name="notes"/>
       <button name="set_age" string="MY test function" type="object" />
     </form>
     </field>
</record>

<!--Student Action-->
<record id="action_student_student" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name='name'>Student Information</field>
  <field name='res_model'>student.student</field>
  <field name='view_type'>form</field>
  <field name='view_mode'>tree,form</field>
</record>


<!--Student Menu-->
<menuitem id="student_parent" name="Student"/>
<menuitem id="menu_student_parent" name="Student Management" parent="student_parent"></menuitem>
<menuitem action="action_student_student" id="menu_student_student" parent="menu_student_parent" string="Result"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

This set_age() method should set student's age at 33 for all students

Comment: Update your code with correct indentation for better understanding

Comment: Yeah sorry, the set_age is inside the class
I'll update it, give me a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Function is not callable that's why this error, check your function indentation, here your code is working fine. Restart the server and upgrade your module, it will work.

Comment: So, it's always better to restart the server when i modify something?

Comment: Okay, thanks. A flash question, what is the syntax of "confirm" in the "<button>" tag? Thanks again ^^

Comment: Where is that?  <button name="function_name" string="Buttons String" type="object" />

Comment: @barbaanto, every time you make a change on your python files, you have to restart openerp's server in order them to take effect (restart will recompile your python code). When you change your XML files you have to go to Settings »» Modules »» Installed Modules and Upgrade your module!

Comment: I'd like to add it because my boss asked it to me.  And thanks Filipe :)